# Access node attribute using simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm using simplexml and I have the following xml:

```
<Entry entryType="Wider Image" entryName="test B and A" entryID="guid">
```

I need to access the entryName attribute. How do I do this?

Comment: `$xml->Entry->attributes()->entryName`?

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php In this case, you are accessing an attribute, so use `$xml->Entry['entryName']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SimpleXML, as you said, it's quite easy. See the example below (please excuse the poor formatting):

```
 <?php 
 $str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Entries>
 <Entry entryType="Wider Image" entryName="test B and A" entryID="guid" />
 </Entries>';

 $sXml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);

 echo $sXml->Entry->attributes()->entryName;
 ?>
```